# Is it possible to read, using open graph, on a server side if user is logged in to facebook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth, facebook-opengraph

Someone is logged in to Facebook and than goes to my website. Is it possible to read on a server side if he's logged in to facebook now. I need to show different fields for a comment form. At the moment I'm using Rails and http://github.com/jugend/fgraph plugin

Answer (score 0):

If they have authenticated with your facebook app before and are currently logged into Facebook, then you would be able to read from the server side that they are logged in by looking at the header cookies that were sent over.  The cookie name is in the format of "fbs_999999999999", where 999999999999 is your app id.  If you would like to know if the user is logged into Facebook but hasn't granted access to your application, you would need to partner with Facebook to get "[Instant Personalization](https://www.facebook.com/instantpersonalization/)" enabled on your application. Or, in the not-so-legal department, you can check out [this article](https://grepular.com/Abusing_HTTP_Status_Codes_to_Expose_Private_Information) which provides a non-approved way of detecting if they are logged into Facebook.